# Add additional WMS' to OpenLayers-Map

Tags: javascript, html, maps, openlayers

I am currently running against a wall, I tested different things from different websites but none of them did work for me. I am really new to WMS/HTML/OpenLayers and all this stuff, but I want to do this.

I am able to add a single WMS (OSM) to my website but if I try to add another one, e.g. Topo+ it will not show it. I can not even say what is not working, I basically just want to add another WMS (right now, later on, I want to add even more data from another GeoServer)

This is working:

```
var center_start = [495445, 5715029];
var zoom_start = 4;

var projection25832 = new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'EPSG:25832',
        // The extent is used to determine zoom level 0. Recommended values for a
        // projection's validity extent can be found at https://epsg.io/.
    extent: [-1877994.66, 3932281.56, 1836715.13, 9440581.95],
    units: 'm'
}); 
 


map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: '"OSM (grau)',
            visible: true,
            baseLayer: true,
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({                        
                url: 'https://ows.terrestris.de/osm-gray/service?',
                    params: {                            
                        'LAYERS': 'OSM-WMS',
                        'VERSION': '1.1.0',
                        'FORMAT': 'image/png',
                        'TILED': false
                    }
                })
            })
                
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: projection25832,
        center: center_start,
        zoom: zoom_start
    })
            
});
```

This is the last thing I tried for getting both Layers in there:

```
var center_start = [495445, 5715029];
var zoom_start = 4;

var projection25832 = new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'EPSG:25832',
        // The extent is used to determine zoom level 0. Recommended values for a
        // projection's validity extent can be found at https://epsg.io/.
    extent: [-1877994.66, 3932281.56, 1836715.13, 9440581.95],
    units: 'm'
}); 


view: new ol.View({
        projection: projection25832,
        center: center_start,
        zoom: zoom_start
    })


var OSM = new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: 'OSM (grau)',
    visible: true,
    baseLayer: true,
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'https://ows.terrestris.de/osm-gray/service?',
            params: {
               'LAYERS': "OSM-WMS",
               'VERSION': '1.1.0',
               'FORMAT': 'image/png',
               'TILED': false
            }
   })
})
OSM.set('name', "OSM (grau)")

var Topo = new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: "Topo+",
    visible: true,
    opacity: 0.6,
    baseLayer: false,
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url:"https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/wms_topplus_open?",
            params:{
                'LAYERS': "p25",
                'TILED': false
            }
    })
})

Topo.set('name', "TopoPlus")   

var layers = [Topo, OSM];

var map = new ol.Map({
      layers: layers,
      target: 'map',
      view: view
      })
    });
```

If anyone can help me/link me to a place so I understand this I would be really happy.

This is the index-File I am using, just to make sure everything is there in case it has something to do with this.

```
 <div id="map"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Openlayesr JS fIle -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Our map file -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSM is a fully opaque base layer while Topo is partly transparent overlay, so to see Topo you must order the layers `[OSM, Topo]`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>

var center_start = [495445, 5715029];
var zoom_start = 4;

var projection25832 = new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'EPSG:25832',
        // The extent is used to determine zoom level 0. Recommended values for a
        // projection's validity extent can be found at https://epsg.io/.
    extent: [-1877994.66, 3932281.56, 1836715.13, 9440581.95],
    units: 'm'
}); 

var OSM = new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: 'OSM (grau)',
    visible: true,
    baseLayer: true,
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'https://ows.terrestris.de/osm-gray/service?',
            params: {
               'LAYERS': "OSM-WMS",
               'VERSION': '1.1.0',
               'FORMAT': 'image/png',
               'TILED': false
            }
   })
})

var Topo = new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: "Topo+",
    visible: true,
    opacity: 0.6,
    baseLayer: false,
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url:"https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/wms_topplus_open?",
            params:{
                'LAYERS': "p25",
                'TILED': false
            }
    })
})

var layers = [OSM, Topo];

var map = new ol.Map({
      layers: layers,
      target: 'map',
      view: new ol.View({
        projection: projection25832,
        center: center_start,
        zoom: zoom_start
      })
    });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```